# JavaScript is excuting too quickly to catch errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the pub / sub jQuery plugin by Peter Higgins. I have run into a problem with JavaScript validation.

This is the crux of the problem...

```
$.subscribe('/make', function(form_id, fields, path, type) { 
    for (var i=0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        $.publish('/validation/field', [ path+'check_field', $('*[name="'+fields[i]+'"]'), fields ]);
    }

    if ($('#'+form_id+' .error').length > 0) {
        alert('There are errors, please fix the errors before continuing.');
        return;
    }
```

The /validation/field will append errors to form fields. When you run this the first time the errors appear but everything is running so quickly an ajax request is sent to save the form. When the form is run the second time the function is stopped correctly as the error classes have been counted.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If the validation is asynchronous

...the usual way you deal with this is to use a callback. In this case, you'd be looking for a callback defined by the validation that tells you when the validation has finished, at which point you could use your code for counting the resulting errors.

#### If the validation is *synchronous*

The above assumes that the validation involves an asynchronous activity of some kind. It doesn't look like [that pub/sub plugin](http://higginsforpresident.net/js/static/jq.pubsub.js) provides any asynchronicity, so this would be down to what your subscriber for `/validation/field` does. If it does an ajax call or a `setTimeout` or similar, then you'll need a callback.

If the `/validation/field` subscriber does the validation *synchronously*, then I'm surprised you're having a problem with the fields not being counted correctly afterward. But if you are, you can probably solve it by giving the browser just a moment to breathe:

```
$.subscribe('/make', function(form_id, fields, path, type) { 
    for (var i=0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        $.publish('/validation/field', [ path+'check_field', $('*[name="'+fields[i]+'"]'), fields ]);
    }

    // Check results *after* giving the browser a moment to breathe:
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('#'+form_id+' .error').length > 0) {
            alert('There are errors, please fix the errors before continuing.');
            return;
        }
        // (...your code left off here, but I'm guessing the rest of the
        // function would also need to be within this new anonymous function...)
    }, 0);
}
```

The `0` parameter to `setTimeout` means "call me back in zero milliseconds", but no browser will actually do that — it'll typically be 4-10 milliseconds later. The point is that it *will* be asynchronous, after the browser has had a chance to catch up and re-invoke the JavaScript layer.

**Be careful though**, make **sure** that the thing doing the validating is doing it synchronously. If it isn't, if it's doing anything async, then the above introduces a race condition into your code where sometimes it will seem to work, other times it won't work. Race conditions will bite you, so double-check. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Dows the subscribe use ajax to call the server?

If wo then thats is your problem as ajax is asyncornious.

The subscribe method then exits immediatly after sending the call, and the function is called on ajax response.

This means that any code after the subscribe is called probably before the ajax request finishes and there will not be any errors yet.

You need then to move aany code folowing the subscribe call into the callback methos instead to be sure it is called after the ajax call.

To prevent any other action you could set a globalvariable, ex. validating = true, and have any other code check that.